# Survival distribution's parameter estimation in R with MLE

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, exponential-distribution, weibull-distribution, mortality

I have [this](http://textuploader.com/d46uz) life table, where:

- qx: the probability that someone aged exactly x will die before reaching age (x+1)
- dx:  the number of people who die age x last birthday
- lx: the number of people who survive to age x

I want to estimate in R the exponential distribution's, the Weibull's, the Gompertz-Makeham's parameter, with this life table. I want the best fitting parameters. How can i begin this?

Comment: 1. Note that the hazard function of a real life table is more complicated than a bathtub-hazard - [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/4d/USGompertzCurve.svg/330px-USGompertzCurve.svg.png) is more or less what a life table hazard function looks like - and none of those can even fit a bathtub (exponential is flat, Gompertz-Makeham and Weibull fitted to such data will be monotonic increasing). 2. The original survival data from which such a life table was estimated -- the deaths and exposures -- are not given. What's your fitting criterion, then? i.e. what are you optimizing?

Comment: I just want the distributions parameters then calculate this distributions survival functions then plotting it. I want approximate the qx with differenciált distribution